# Disable the swipe action in table view cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have implemented the swipe action for the table view cell and they are two actions: `Accept` and `Reject`.

When I swipe for the first time it must appear and for the second time if I swipe the cell it should not open.

The swipe action for the cell must be in the disabled mode.

Comment: please read this first : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

First, you should keep track of the indexPath of cells you have interacted with.

```swift
private var disabledCellsIndexPath = [IndexPath]()
```

Then in the method to configure your swipe actions ([this is the new iOS 11 API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipeactionsconfiguration)):

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Action Title", handler: { _, _, completionHandler in

        // DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE
        // …

        // This is where you specify that this specific cell should be 'disabled'
        self?.disabledCellsIndexPath.append(indexPath)

        completionHandler(true)
    })

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return !disabledCellsIndexPath.contains(indexPath)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  allowEdit flag when you want `swipe Enable`. else make it false.

```
var allowEdit: Bool = true
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return allowEdit
    }



     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
        {
           if allowEdit{
               /*to perform Accept and Reject action on row*/
           }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this code. But no change it is not disabled

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, Please follow following generalize idea,

> > You can manage the flag for that indexPath in app end database. Whenever required open or disable i.e manage it you can enable/disable the edit action for that indexPath.